# Filtering jqGrid by multiple conditions at client side

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I have a jqGrid with some records and want to filter the records based on multiple conditions.

For instance, if there are three columns, Name, Age and City and I want to filter the grid on the following condition:

```
Name = "Mark" and Age = 25 and City = 'NY'
```

the following code works fine-

```
 var grid = jQuery("#memberDetails");
 var postdata = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'postData');

 var filterArray = new Array();
 var filterConidtion; 

 filterConidtion = new Object();
 filterConidtion.field = "name";
 filterConidtion.op = "eq";
 filterConidtion.data = "Mark";
 filterArray.push(filterConidtion);

 filterConidtion = new Object();
 filterConidtion.field = "Age";
 filterConidtion.op = "eq";
 filterConidtion.data = "25";
 filterArray.push(filterConidtion);

 filterConidtion = new Object();
 filterConidtion.field = "City";
 filterConidtion.op = "eq";
 filterConidtion.data = "NY";
 filterArray.push(filterConidtion);

 jQuery.extend(postdata, {
        filters: {
            "groupOp": "and",
            "rules": filterArray
        }
    });

 grid.jqGrid('setGridParam', {
            search: true,
            postData: postdata
    });

 grid.trigger("reloadGrid", [{
        page: 1
    }]);
```

but I am not sure how to make the following filter work:

```
Name = "Mark" and Age = 25 and (City = 'NY' OR City = 'FL')
```

The `groupOp` works either on AND or on OR condition, not sure how to embed a sub condition within the `groupOp`

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Format of `filters` are described in [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:advanced_searching#options). To implement more complex searching criteria one can use `groups` property of `filters`. The corresponding code could be about the following:

```
var $grid = $("#memberDetails");

$.extend($grid.jqGrid("getGridParam", "postData"), {
    filters: JSON.stringify({
        groupOp: "AND",
        rules: [
            { field: "Name", op: "eq", data: "Mark" },
            { field: "Age",  op: "eq", data: "25" }
        ],
        groups: [
            {
                groupOp: "OR",
                rules: [
                    { field: "City", op: "eq", data: "NY" },
                    { field: "City", op: "eq", data: "FL" }
                ],
                groups: []
            }
        ]
    })
});
$grid.jqGrid("setGridParam", {search: true})
     .trigger('reloadGrid', [{current: true, page: 1}]);
```