# JQGrid Reset Filter and Load Entire Data Back

Tags: jqgrid, filter, reset

How can i reset the filter in JQGrid and get back entire data?

Somehow i have to create parameters like:

```
_search false
filters {"groupOp":"AND","rules":[]}
nd      1363780609723
page    1
rows    20
sidx    application_name
sord    asc
```

I tried below code

```
var grid = $("#list");
grid.jqGrid('setGridParam',{search:false});
var postData = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam','postData');
$.extend(postData,{filters:""});
grid.trigger("reloadGrid",[{page:1}]);
```

But it generates the parameters like

```
_search false
filters 
nd      1363780823111
page    1
rows    20
sidx    application_name
sord    asc
```

I just need to send filter parameter like this but don't know how

```
filters {"groupOp":"AND","rules":[]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see no difference in the meaning between empty `filters` and `{"groupOp":"AND","rules":[]}`. If you really need to set `{"groupOp":"AND","rules":[]}` as filter you can change the line `$.extend(postData,{filters:""});` to

```js
$.extend(postData, {
    filters: JSON.stringify({groupOp: "AND", rules:[]})
});
```

see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13247251/315935) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5273385/315935) for code examples.