# How to search records in jqgrid dynamically as I have to apply search on the same data in different requests

Tags: jquery, json, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I have a page master tracker which is showing some records along with the status,

My question is ...How can I search the records on the basis of the status dynamically?

I searched the problem but no results, all the are are providing is filter toolbar or dynamic filters in search option,
In my situation I need to search without hitting the search icon from the JSON data I received.

I am using following code to filter the jqgrid data

```
var searchFilter = $('input[id$="hfSearchFilter"]').val()
   f (searchFilter != "")
   {
      var grid = $("#jQGridDemo"), f;
      f = { groupOp: "OR", rules: [] };
      f.rules.push({ field: "STATUS", op: "eq", data: searchFilter });
      grid[0].p.search = true;
      $.extend(grid[0].p.postData, { filters: JSON.stringify(f) });
      grid.trigger("reloadGrid", [{ page: 1, current: true }]);
   }
```

I have data like,

```
 Type         status

Employement    WIP

education      WIP

Court          On Hold

Reference      WIP
```

from the above code my requirement is to filter just "On Hold" records as my search filter is On Hold only

I dont want the user to click on search button as I want the filtered records on page load out of the received json data.

any help?

Comment: If you use `datatype: "local"` then you can filter/search locally. You need to set `search: true` option, set `filters` property of `postData` option and trigger `reloadGrid` finally. See [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5750127/315935), [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13247251/315935), [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5273385/315935) and so on.

Comment: hello Oleg, I have provided the code which i am using to filter the jqgrid but it is not working as expected.